# Telegraf - inputs.procstat procstat Plugin - README.md doc - exe, pid_file, command line pattern username

Tags: sudo, pid, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin, procstat

Using: **Telegraf v1.0.1**

Telegraf procstat plugin's documentation:
https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/procstat

My custom config File:
 **/etc/telegraf/telegraf.d/my_custom_process_service-telegraf.conf** contains:

```
[[inputs.procstat]]
  exe = "."
  prefix = "service_process"

[[inputs.procstat]]
  pid_file = "/var/run/jenkins/jenkins.pid"
  prefix = "service_process"
```

The above configuration works fine per the syntax. This will give me metrics with metric's name starting: `procstat.service.process.xx.xx`(depending upon if you are converting `_` with a `.` character) -or simply `procstat.service_process.x.x` metrics.

To catch any process running on the machine using `exe = "."` (it will do a `pgrep "."` operation and) to find all processes running on the machine by giving `process_name=<processes>` values; -OR using, `pid_file = /var/run/jenkins/jenkins.pid` (NOTE: Provided you have READ permission for the user which is running `telegraf` service) for processes which run behind Java/other wrappers; If you give `pid_file = /var/run/jenkins/jenkins.pid` and if Jenkins is running under user `jenkins` and **/var/run/jenkins** folder doesn't have at least "`r-x`" access + read "`r`" access on the pid file itself, then it'll will throw and error about "permission denied".

```
2017-01-10T18:13:30Z E! Error: procstat getting process, exe: [] pidfile: [/var/run/jenkins/jenkins.pid] pattern: [] user: [] Failed to read pidfile '/var/run/jenkins/jenkins.pid'. Error: 'open /var/run/jenkins/jenkins.pid: permission denied'
```

**Question:**

Is it possible for Telegraf to run in `SUDO` mode (if possible)? i.e. if I don't have `r-x/r` access to read a process's PID file and assuming there are lots of such processes (running behind Java/some Wrapper, so `exe=xxxx` won't work in such cases), then I have to use `pid_file = ...` method, then how can I have Telegraf working with this `pid_file` method for getting the `process_name` as `jenkins` or `nexus` etc.

**PS**: Doing `chmod -R 775_or_755 /var/run` on every host may not be feasible.

If I do give 755 permission at /var/ran/jenkins folder and 644 to jenkins.pid file, the permission error will go away. After this I tried to use metric: `procstat.service.process.cpu.usage` against process `jenkins` (i.e. `process_name="jenkins"`) but it's not finding `jenkins` as it's value. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Shortened my post a bit and opened another post for my other question. Is this a legit question now or still too broad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added the following config in /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d/someFile.conf and fixed the permission issue using `Ansible's file module`: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/file_module.html

```
## Telegraf filestat plugin
[[inputs.filestat]]
  files = ["/var/run/*/*.pid","/var/run/*.pid"]

## To catch all processs. Better than pattern = "."
[[inputs.procstat]]
  exe = "."
  prefix = "pgrep_serviceprocess"

##For catching processes by a user.
## Telegraf will use: pgrep -u <user>
[[inputs.procstat]]
  user = "vagrant"
  prefix = "pgrep_serviceprocess"

[[inputs.procstat]]
  user = "telegraf"
  prefix = "pgrep_serviceprocess"

[[inputs.procstat]]
  user = "root"
  prefix = "pgrep_serviceprocess"

## Add more users or template it out in Ansible.
```